# How can I speed up this graph algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, haskell, graph

Full disclosure: I'm writing this as part of a [hackerrank.com challenge](https://www.hackerrank.com/contests/lambda-calculi-may14/challenges/prison-transport).

As part of my algorithm, I have to take a list of pairs and produce a list of sets.
Each pair represents a link between two nodes, and each Set represents all nodes that are linked to each other (directly and indirectly).

The pairs are in the form of a list because that is how they are generated and I don't want to waste time re-boxing them in a tuple. Besides, the irrefutable pattern removes most of this overhead.

```
import Data.List
import Data.Maybe
import qualified Data.IntSet as IS (fromList)

mkgroups :: [[Int]] -> [IntSet]
mkgroups = foldl' add2gc []
  where
    -- if a group is not found, create a new group
    add2gc [] is = [IS.fromList is]
    -- for the current group,
    add2gc (g:gc) ~is@[i1, i2]
      -- if either mates in group, add to group.
      | i1 `IS.member` g = merge2gc i2 g gc
      | i2 `IS.member` g = merge2gc i1 g gc
      -- otherwise try next group
      | otherwise = g : add2gc gc is
    -- merge other inmate to appropriate group
    merge2gc i g gc
      -- in original group, return original group
      | i `IS.member` g = g:gc
      | otherwise = case part (IS.member i) gc of
      -- in any other group, merge that group with this.
        (Just g',gs) -> (IS.union g g') : gs
      -- otherwise add innmate to this group
        _ -> (IS.insert i g):gc
```

Instead of `partition`, I needed a function that would return the first match and a list of all non-matching entities. using this function instead of partition changes the algorithm from O(n^2) closer to O(n*log n) amortised (and brought my runtime down by 15%)

```
part p as = go as []
  where 
    go []     ps  = (Nothing, ps)
    go (a:as) ps = if p a
      then (Just a, ps ++ as)
      else go as (a:ps)
```

I have also tried to select the best datastructure for the job. Originally the groups were `[[Int]]` and that actually worked pretty well (in that moving to `[IntSet]` only improved runtime by 30%).

Still, I need to make this even faster. My very last test is timing out at 8 seconds, and I have no visibility into the input data behind the test. It could be hitting a worst-case path, or even just be a massive blob of data. I've tried just about everything I know of to make this faster, even using my knowledge that there will always be 2 elements in the inner input list to make one match irrefutable. Currently I'm attempting to get my local GHC install and packages rebuilt with profiling data to try and profile the code in depth.

Is there anything that the SO Haskell masters can see or think of that I haven't tried yet?

---

**EDIT:** I think that the algorithm I currently have is a reasonable interpretation of the goal I had in mind, although it suffers from a lot of copying on set insert. Hence, thanks to @fizruk et. al., I reimplemented using `Data.Graph` from the standard library.

```
import Data.Tree as T
import Data.Graph as G

mkgroups :: Int -> [(Int,Int)] -> Forest Vertex
mkgroups n = filter ((>1) . length . T.flatten) . G.components . G.buildG (0,n)
```

This does the job very nicely, and runs a whole lot quicker (about 4x). Thanks to everyone who helped. I decided to award answer to @phil_20686 because after reading the library source, it seems that his answer is closest to what the library actually does.

Comment: Have you considered using [Data.Graph](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers/docs/Data-Graph.html) from `containers` package? You should be able to build graph using `buildG` and get all connected components (is that what you want?) using `components`.

Comment: No I haven't tried Data.Graph yet. I'll let you know how it goes.

Comment: Nice, didn't know Data.Graph was in the "standard library". I got accepted with 10 lines of code using `components`

Comment: Thanks @fizruk, That did the trick. Do you happen to know what algorithm this uses that makes it so quick?

Comment: @Thomas `components` is just `dff . undirected`. `undirected` makes graph undirected and `dff` builds a spanning forest of the graph. You can [look at the sources](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.5.5.1/docs/src/Data-Graph.html#dff) to learn more.

Comment: @Thomas It uses [depth-first search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search) with adjacency arrays as suggested by phil's answer below. To maintain the visited set, it uses a mutable array inside the `ST` monad. This is one of the applications where it would probably easier to just use an imperative language, unless somebody has already hidden the ugly details in a library like `Data.Graph` :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you have constructed the appropriate data structures, you can solve this in linear time using breadth first or depth first search.

However, constructing the data structures is not necessarily trivially in either time or memory. E.g. you could put ever element into a pair of multimaps (one for incoming and one outgoing). Then you can implement a BFS trivially by just going to the appropriate keys, and getting all of the connected nodes. If you remove them from the map you insure that you don't repeat yourself.

Since maps are constructed in linear time in the number of values (nodes), and BFS is linear in the number of edges, the performance will be O(E+V).

Comment: Er, maps are constructed in linear time in the number of nodes, really? And BFS is linear in the number of edges? These seem to rely at least on an assumption that inserting and deleting particular elements from your map is a constant-time operation, which sounds suspicious to me.

Comment: For those with suspicions like mine, these are well addressed by Niklas B. in the comment thread attached to my answer.

Comment: E.g. a hash map has O(1) insertion and deletion provided it was appropriately sized to start with, so N elements can be added in O(N) for most practicable purposes. Admittedly, very large hash tables with large numbers of bins can take a non trivial time to initialise the empty map, but if that were the case, probably no in-memory solution would be very effective.

Answer (score 2):

The union-find algorithm is designed to be bloody fast at a closely related problem. A [Hackage search](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/search?terms=union-find) suggests there are several packages implementing this algorithm, which you may be interested in checking out. However, as discussed in the comments below, the verbiage "closely related" is actually load-bearding in this case: union-find solves a slightly harder problem, and as a result will not be actually optimal. Namely, a union-find structure will be able to, given two nodes in your graph, optimally quickly tell you whether they are part of the same connected component.

Comment: union-find for connected components is a bit overkill though, DFS is much simpler and faster (both asymptotically and in practice)

Comment: @NiklasB. Are you sure? I would think constructing the graph you do DFS in is already more expensive than building the union-find structure, before you even start your search.

Comment: It's linear time, i.e. optimal. You are given the edge list, which is easy to convert to an adjacency list representation. DFS and BFS are also linear time -> optimal. In contrast, union-find is at least Omega(alpha(n) * n), which, granted, is pretty good, but harder to implement and certainly has a larger constant factor

Comment: @NiklasB. I see. You are making an assumption (given by the link but not by the question here) that the nodes in the graph are drawn from a small, dense set. I can see how that would simplify some things. I still think it's quite valuable to give a good way of solving this problem for graphs that do not have this property.

Comment: Well if they were constant size (i.e. word size), you could use a hash table and again get linear time [w.h.p.](http://www.algorithmist.com/index.php/With_high_probability) and very fast in practice. The union-find approach would experience the same penalty however

Comment: @NiklasB. If the inputs are constant size, all kinds of asymptotic analyses collapse, yes. As far as I'm concerned, that just means that, while the assumption is realistic, it is hiding something important about the problem domain. In reality our computers are just giant DFAs, but that's not a very satisfactory base for analyzing them because it throws out lots of interesting information about how to use them effectively.

Comment: I mean, constant space per node ID, which is in fact very realistic. But apart from that, the thing is, a union-find based algorithm will always be a factor of alpha(n) slower, no matter how you turn it because you need to look up nodes just as often, so you have the exact same problem :)

Comment: @NiklasB. Okay. I see your point now. Will amend the answer shortly.

Comment: I guess I'm being pedantic here, I like to be on around [algorithm], so bear with me..

Comment: @NiklasB. (An aside per your defense of "constant space per node ID" being realistic: I actually did not claim your assumption was unrealistic in the first place! =)

Comment: I see that now. My formulation was indeed bad, I should have said "constant number of words" and still be able to enjoy meaningful asymptotic analysis inside the RAM model with O(1) ops but without bounding the input size